# How to get a required error message for radio buttons using FluentValidation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, fluentvalidation

I am using `ASP.NET MVC 4` and the latest `FluentValidation`.

I am struggling to get my radio buttons to validate.  When I click the submit button I need a selection in the radio button list.

In my view I have the following:

```
@model MyProject.ViewModels.Servers.ServicesViewModel
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ComponentTypeId)
@foreach (var componentType in Model.ComponentTypes)
{
     <div>
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ComponentTypeId, componentType.Id, new { id = "emp" + componentType.Id })
          @Html.Label("emp" + componentType.Id, componentType.Name)
     </div>
}
```

My ComponentType class:

```
public class ComponentType : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Part of my action method where I set the properties of my view model:

```
ServicesViewModel viewModel = new ServicesViewModel
{
     ComponentTypes = componentTypeRepository.FindAll(),
     Domains = domainRepository.FindAll()
};
```

My view model:

```
[Validator(typeof(ServicesViewModelValidator))]
public class ServicesViewModel
{
     public int ComponentTypeId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<ComponentType> ComponentTypes { get; set; }

     public int DomainId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<Domain> Domains { get; set; }
}
```

My validator class:

```
public class ServicesViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ServicesViewModel>
{
     public ServicesViewModelValidator()
     {
          RuleFor(x => x.ComponentTypeId)
               .NotNull()
               .WithMessage("Required");

          RuleFor(x => x.DomainId)
               .NotNull()
               .WithMessage("Required");
     }
}
```

My http Post action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Services(ServicesViewModel viewModel)
{
     Check.Argument.IsNotNull(viewModel, "viewModel");

     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          viewModel.ComponentTypes = componentTypeRepository.FindAll();
          viewModel.Domains = domainRepository.FindAll();

          return View(viewModel);
     }

     return View(viewModel);
}
```

How do I get it to show my required message when nothing selected?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using an `int` for `ComponentId` instead of a nullable `int`. You are then using the `NotNull()` validator which will never trigger since an `int` can not be null.

Try switching it to this:

```
[Validator(typeof(ServicesViewModelValidator))]
public class ServicesViewModel
{
     public int? ComponentTypeId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<ComponentType> ComponentTypes { get; set; }

     public int DomainId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<Domain> Domains { get; set; }
}
```

If that dose not work then you could try to use a range validation:

```
public class ServicesViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ServicesViewModel>
{
     public ServicesViewModelValidator()
     {
          RuleFor(x => x.ComponentTypeId)
               .InclusiveBetween(1, int.MaxValue)
               .WithMessage("Required");

          RuleFor(x => x.DomainId)
               .NotNull()
               .WithMessage("Required");
     }
}
```

That would make it so that 0 is not a valid value.